# Android:TabHost NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-tabhost

Parent View code and there is an refresh button in it:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);  
    final TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();   
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1")      
            .setIndicator("All", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.all))      
            .setContent(new Intent(this, All.class)
            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)));      
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2")      
            .setIndicator("One", getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.one))      
            .setContent(new Intent(this, One.class)
            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)));  
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab3")   
            .setIndicator("Two",getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.two))   
            .setContent(new Intent(this, Two.class)
            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))); 
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab4")   
            .setIndicator("Three",getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.three))   
            .setContent(new Intent(this, Three.class)
            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))); 
    tabHost.getTabWidget().bringToFront();
    setContentView(tabHost);
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,R.layout.title_bar);      
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
}
```

And I define a button in each child view, I ues this

```
refreshButton = (ImageButton) getParent().findViewById(R.id.refresh);
```

to get the button in the parent view but the refreshButton is always null and
 there is an exception:
**java.lang.RuntimeException:Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ParentView}:java.lang.NullPointerException.**

So please help me with this, how can I fix this. Thank you!

Comment: It's helpful to include a stack trace for these type of questions. Judging by what you posted, I would guess that `getParent()` is returning `null`.

Comment: your button `refresh` in which class? and where this code being called `refreshButton = (ImageButton) getParent().findViewById(R.id.refresh);` ??

Comment: I probably know why this happed, because getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,R.layout.title_bar); is run after the OneClass shown, so the button is always null.

Answer (score 0):

Because getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,R.layout.title_bar); is run after the OneClass shown, so the button is always null. I use broadcast to fix this